# Get active filters in observer in magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, event-observer, layered-navigation, filter

I want to change my category display mode if there is active filters. My config.xml is :

```
    <events>
        <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
            <observers>
                <mycustom_module_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mycustom_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>setCategoryDisplayMode</method>
                </mycustom_module_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
    </events>
```

And my observer is method is :

```
public function setCategoryDisplayMode(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
    $appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')
        ->getState()
        ->getFilters();
    if (!empty($appliedFilters)) {
        $category->setDisplayMode("PRODUCTS");
    }
}
```

But I am unable to get active filters with `$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();` Is I am doing something wrong or my event is wrong?

I also tried with `Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State')->getActiveFilters();` but no success.